# Dask restart worker(s) using client

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Is there a way using dask client to restart a worker or worker list provided. Needed a way to bounce a worker after a task is executed to reset the state of the process which may have been changed by the execution.

`Client.restart()` restarts entire grid and so may end up killing any tasks running in parallel to one that just completed.

Comment: This is tracked here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1823

Comment: Thank you. We were also looking for this to utilize it for cancellations of tasks as well as current client.cancel does not kill the task execution on worker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203128/how-do-i-stop-a-running-task-in-dask/49203129#49203129